# Why Undertale won't play again on Steam?

Tags: steam, undertale

I've recently bought Undertale from Ebay for my Steam account.

My daughter was playing the game yesterday but when trying to play again after logging off it wont let her.

We are pressing the play game button but nothing happens! Can someone please explain! Many thanks

Comment: Did you receive a game key from Ebay and activated the key on your account?

Comment: Have you tried restarting your PC and verifying the integrity of the game cache?

Comment: Did you log off your steam account? And have not logged back in now?

Comment: no game key, I dont even know what that is as Im new to all of this stuff! Ive logged in and out and tried it on a different laptop.Whats a game cache?! Oh its so frustrating haha thanks guys..

Comment: It sounds like you haven't played the game very long, so this is probably not the case, but after you've finished the Genocide run (spoilers ahead), opening the game will show just a black screen with a "wind howling" sound. You have to leave that screen open for ten minutes and then you'll have the option to reset the game back to the beginning. It looks like the game has crashed, but that is intended behavior. Thought I'd mention it.

Comment: If you didn't get a game key, exactly what did you buy off eBay that lets you play Undertale?

Answer (score 2):

- Right-click the game in your steam library

  - Click Properties
  - Click the local files tab
  - Click Verify Integrity of Game Cache
  - Steam will verify if the game is missing any files or if any files are corrupted and will redownload them

    [image: Properties option at the botom]

    If it still doesnt work, you can try completely reinstalling the game by:
    (**Be aware that you might lose your progress in the game**)

    - Right-clicking the game in your steam library
  - Click Delete Local Content
  - Confirm By clicking delete
  - Right-Click the game again
  - Install

Comment: @user161840 You also mentionned logging off, when you logged back in, did you make sure it was the same account your daughter was playing on? The game is tied to the account it was registered with, so the other accounts cannot use it

Comment: yes there is just the one account. Ive right clicked on the game but it doesnt give me a properties option?! Im just gunna give up soon Ive had so much hassle with this whole thing! Is there another way of getting the game without steam?

Comment: @user161840 did you right click the game in the **steam library**?

Comment: @user161840 see the screenshot i added to the answer